# scikit-learn predict() new data

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, predict

I have a question regarding the `predict()` function from `scikit-learn`. I'm trying to validate my trained classifier by testing with data, that is not in the training data and also has a different label. So I basically want, that the classifiers output is: 'new data is not predictable'. How do I implement that?

Right now the classifier is just trying to predict the trained labels on the new data with totally different labels. Could you help me out?!

my classifier pipeline:

```
text_clf_NB = Pipeline([('vect', vects_NB),
 ('tfidf', tf_idf_NB),
 ('clf', classifier('NB')) # choose classifier
])
```

my prediction:

```
pred_NB = text_clf_NB.fit(X_train, Y_train).predict(X_others)
```

X_others has a new case with a non-trained label, and I want the classifier to notice, that it is a case not similar to the trained cases and not just predicting what the most likely label of the trained ones is for the new case.

Comment: The classifer doesn't look at the label when classifying/predicting new data. You should just check if the label is not in the list of labels you trained your model on

Comment: Yeah, it is not in the labels of my trained model. No i do not want the classifier to look on the label. But I want the classifier to notice, when a new case is not similar at all to the trained cases, and not just trying to fit any label to it.

Comment: because it always tries to predict any of the trained labels. It is never like, the new case is just not similar at all, so no label fits

Comment: Can you please show us what you're trying already with a code snippet so we can help you solve the problem better?

Comment: I did add some code. I think that the predict() function, is not right for my purpose. I just do not know the way to go for my issue.

Comment: *'new data is not predictable'*, that will not be possible because model does not know the data itself, it only does some mathematical calculations for you. If the input dimensions of the data match, then it will return some results. You can prevent that by if-else statements.

Comment: @Frightera Do you think I could do it as following by using predict.proba() and if statement: saying, I trained two labels. If the probabilites for both cases are close to 50%, then give output: 'no trained label'. Because at 50:50 the model is quite indecisive

Comment: or similar saying, one probability has to be above 70 % for example

Answer (score 1):

Ok, solved the problem like this now. Is this a reasonable way to do it.

```
# prediction probabilites
pred_NB = text_clf_NB.fit(X_train, Y_train).predict_proba(X_test)

# prediction depending on probs
new_pred =[]
case = 0
for pairs in pred_NB: 
        if max(pairs) >= 0.995:
            pred = text_clf_NB.fit(X_train, Y_train).predict([X_test[case]])
        elif max(pairs) < 0.995:
            pred = (["No sufficient similarity to trained cases"])
        case += 1
        new_pred.extend(pred)
            
new_pred
```